# How do I add a batch of models to a collection that already has items?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a news feed. On initialization, the app calls `Collection.fetch()` and receives 20 stories.

Then, when a user clicks "load more", I want to fetch 20 more stories, and add it to the collection. (I will hit a URL to do this.)

However, `.fetch` resets the collection. How can I hit a URL and download more stories without resetting the collection?

Comment: I see this on the [Backbone.js docs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-fetch): `If you'd like to add the incoming models to the current collection, instead of replacing the collection's contents, pass {add: true} as an option to fetch.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass {add: true} as an option to fetch.